# Parse output from string slice into another string slice

Tags: go

My input is

```
[v=spf1 ip4:35.190.247.0/24 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:2.44.5.76/32 ~all]
```

It is of type

```
[]string
```

And the number of elements in it are

```
1
```

My aim is to parse this slice so that my output is of type string slice but contains only the IPs and each IP is a separate element in the slice

Output should look like

```
[35.190.247.0/24 64.233.160.0/19 2.44.5.76/32]
```

Type should be

```
[]string
```

And number of elements should be

```
3
```

So what Im doing is to first replace the `v=spf1 ip4:`

```
j := strings.Replace(t.Txt[0], "v=spf1 ", "", -1)
k := strings.Replace(j, "ip4:", "", -1)
l := strings.Replace(j, "~all", "", -1)
```

This gives me

```
35.190.247.0/24 64.233.160.0/19 2.44.5.76/32
```

of type

```
string
```

Then what I want to do it to iterate though it all with a space as a delimiter and print each individual IP as a separate string on a new line

```
for i, word := range l {
    fmt.Println(word)
}
```

But rather than getting

```
0 35.190.247.0/24 
1 64.233.160.0/19 
2 2.44.5.76/32
```

im getting

```
0 51
1 53
2 46
3 49
4 57
5 48
6 46
```

Whats the issue here ? Im unable to figure it out

Comment: Ranging over a string gives you *runes*, not "words". Try using `strings.Split`. See the table of range expression here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

Answer (score 0):

By using `range l`, you are iterating on the rune of the strings. In your case these are just the ASCII codes of the ip addresses.

You were not far from the solution:

```golang
j := strings.Replace(t.Txt[0], "v=spf1 ", "", -1)
k := strings.Replace(j, "ip4:", "", -1)
l := strings.Replace(j, " ~all", "", -1) // <- I added a space in front of "~all".
res := strings.Split(l, " ")
```

Res is now a slice with three strings, each one corresponding to an IP address.

You could have also used the following code to achieve the same result.

```golang
l := strings.Replace(t.Txt[0][7:len(t.Txt[0])-5], "ip4:", "", -1)
res := strings.Split(l, " ")
```